# automatically populate arrays

Tags: php, arrays, automation

Strangely enough I haven't found any question or answers to my problem (should be quite basic), so I will ask it here.

in PHP If I have an array named myArray that I don't know the contents of, then I can't do this:

```
$myArray[20] = "some string";
```

because entry 20 may already exist.

So is there a way to automatically insert a string as the last entry, so nothing is overwritten in the array?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: That site says that rather than using array_push, to assign like this $array[] = $var; Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add the new item to your array like:

```
$myArray[] = "some string";
```

This would automatically add it to the end of your existing array without overwriting existing array entries.